# Progressive greasing the groove

Tags: training, bodyweight-exercises

Attached some pull up bars all over the place, got one in my office and 5 in my home.

Gave myself a rule to always crank some bar to sternum chin ups everytime I pass by the bar.

It's been great, contrary to what I expected the blood and warmth always in my arms doesn't sore, it's pleasing actually.

But for the future, what are some ways to safely progress the greasing the groove? To do more and harder whilist mainting that pleasing warmth.

More details: in the morning it's harder and I usually only do sets of 4 then as I get more warmed up I can easily crank sets of 11 by the time it gets night out.

Comment: Pullup variations: typewriters, triangles/circles, offset/towels, etc.

Comment: Don't forget to also exercise the auxiliary muscles that augment pull-ups.  Core exercises are key.

Comment: change your grip often, use accessories eg. rings, cannonballs, ropes etc